# Flutter: pull_to_refresh horizontally, it just refreshes without pulling

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
          height: 200,
          width: context.width,
          child: SmartRefresher(
            enablePullDown: false,
            enablePullUp: true,
            controller: RefreshController(initialRefresh: false),
            onRefresh: () {},
            onLoading: () {},
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (c, i) =>
                  Card(child: Center(child: Text(i.toString()))),
              itemExtent: 100.0,
              itemCount: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I have this `pull_to_refresh` widget. It works fine but the problem is that it refreshes when I reach item 10. How can I make it to refresh when there is a proper pull physics applied to the list?